# How to automate ImportJSON function in Google Sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, auto-update

I am a beginner in terms of using Google Scripts/any coding languages but could really do with some help in automating data import from the Environment Agency Real-Time flood monitoring API.  The API addresses are below:

https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023003/readings?latest
https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023004/readings?latest
https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023020/readings?latest

I need to schedule a trigger to refresh the information I import every 10-15 minutes.  Therefore, I need to script my API import.  I have tried using the following IMPORTJSON code from https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs

However, from what I understand, this is a generic code which allows me to use the IMPORTJSON function within Google Sheets.  I need an additional function which allows me to schedule a trigger for every 10-15 minutes to refresh the information within my Google Sheet.
I have also tried scripting to parse the JSON API but the items array is causing difficulties. This is the script I currently have:

```
function FloodEWS() {

var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(“https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023004/readings.json?latest"); 
var content = res.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var context = json["@context"];
  var meta = json["meta"];
  var items = json["items"]
  Logger.log(items);
}
```

The API I am trying to parse is below - the "value" and "dateTime" is what I need to extract from the items array (and have automated):

```
{ 
  "@context" : "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/meta/context.jsonld" ,
  "meta" : { 
    "publisher" : "Environment Agency" ,
    "licence" : "http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/doc/open-government-licence/version/3/" ,
    "documentation" : "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/doc/reference" ,
    "version" : "0.9" ,
    "comment" : "Status: Beta service" ,
    "hasFormat" : [ "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023003/readings.csv?latest", "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023003/readings.rdf?latest", "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023003/readings.ttl?latest", "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023003/readings.html?latest" ]
  }
   ,
  "items" : [ { 
    "@id" : "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/data/readings/023003-level-stage-i-15_min-m/2020-08-26T09-15-00Z" ,
    "dateTime" : "2020-08-26T09:15:00Z" ,
    "measure" : "http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/023003-level-stage-i-15_min-m" ,
    "value" : 1.68
  }
 ]
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: *I have also tried scripting to parse the JSON API* [Edit] to show that script and specific  issue you're having. See [mcve]

Comment: `var value=items[0]["value"]`

Comment: Thanks so much! When I edited my script, it said "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (line 3, file "Code.gs")"

Comment: There is a syntax error with quotes. Use straight quotes on both ends.

Comment: That's worked! Sorry I am just a beginner! How would I then take those values and put them into my Google Sheet?

Comment: See first question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script?tab=Votes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

You can still use the `ImportJSON` function provided by this [script](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs) and save it to a separate google script in the script editor.

Then you can use the following function to paste the `ImportJSON` formulas for all the URLs to `Sheet1`:

```
function updateData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getMaxRows(),sh.getMaxColumns()).clearContent();
  
  const urls = ["https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023003/readings?latest",
              "https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023004/readings?latest",
              "https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023020/readings?latest"];
  
  urls.forEach(url=>{
               
               sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1).setValue(`=ImportJSON("${url}")`);
               SpreadsheetApp.flush();
             }
)
}
```

In order to setup a 10 minutes time-trigger for `updateData()` you can execute the following code once:

```
function create_Trigger(){
ScriptApp.newTrigger("updateData")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(10)
  .create();
}
```

### Result:

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I have got this message though when I run the first script you sent: Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. (line 5, file "Data")

Comment: Do you have a sheet with the name `Sheet1` as you can see from the screenshot I provided in my answer ?

Comment: The problem has been solved! So once I run the trigger function once, I do not need to do anything else?

Comment: Also, if I want to apply formulae to the " values" numbers, will the formulas be applied automatically to the new numbers?

Comment: @LukeHewitson I updated my answer. Please check if `updateData()` works as a standalone function. And then you can run the trigger function once to setup the process. Also don't forget to add the ImportJSON code (from github) to a separate .gs file in script editor.

Comment: The update(Data) function works standalone yes, as does the trigger function.  My script seems to be working.

Comment: @LukeHewitson the answer is yes. However, put the formulas on a different sheet because Sheet1 is cleared everytime there is old data.

Comment: Finally, if I need to trigger an email based on a cell value, is there a code for this?

Comment: There are many resources for this, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583581/sending-emails-based-on-cell-values Please accept my answer if it solved your question.

Comment: I am unsure whether the trigger is working correctly as I can see that one of the URLs has not updated to the latest figures

Comment: @LukeHewitson are you sure that the data changed ? Maybe it does not get updated every 10 minutes

Comment: When I visit the <https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/stations/023004/readings?latest>  API, the latest data is 11:30 and 1.015 value, this is not reflected in my spreadsheet

Comment: Also my spreadsheet seems to be refreshing/clearing every minute, sometimes even more often than that